# How to xml to php nested arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I 'm a total PHP beginner and need some help :-)

Have this xml:

http://pastebin.com/ZSpNPhXH

And this scrypt:

```
 <?php

// Retrieve XML File
$file = file_get_contents('livescore-feed.xml');

// Parse XML with SimpleXML
$livescore_data = new SimpleXMLElement($file);


foreach ($livescore_data->league as $league) {

    echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>";


    echo "<thead><tr><th colspan='6' id='league'>" . $league->attributes()->name . "</th></tr></thead>";

    echo "<tbody>";
    foreach ($league->match as $match) {




        $status = $match->attributes()->status;
        $home = $match->home->attributes()->name;
        $away = $match->away->attributes()->name;
        $score = $match->home->attributes()->goals . " - " . $match->away->attributes()->goals;

        // If match not yet started, there will be a ":" in 'status' attribute
        if (strpos($match->attributes()->status,':') !== false) {
            $score = "-";
        }



        echo "<tr><td class='status' id='match'>" . $status . "</td><td id='match' colspan='2'>" .
            $home . "</td><td class='score' id='match'>" . $score . "</td><td id='match' colspan='2'>" .
            $away . "</td>


              </tr>";

    }


    echo "</tbody></table>";
}
```

?>

How to show/parse "events" also

Thank you very much for your help and suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same way you parse other data!

```
foreach( $livescore_data->league as $league )
{
    (...)
    foreach( $league->match as $match ) 
    {
        (...)
        #        ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
        foreach( $match->events->event as $event ) 
        {
            echo $event['assist'] . '<br>';
            echo $event['player'] . '<br>';
            (...)
        }
    }
}
```

You have to perform a loop through `$match->events->event` and you can get each `<event>` attribute using `$event[attribute]` syntax. So, `$event['extra_min']`, `$event['minute']`, etc...

You have only to adapt the code to your table structure.